# shell script to add to the

Tags: awk, sed

i need to append to an xml file by reading from an csv file

i/p file pattern 
test.dat

```
account,bill,bill seg
12345,12445,121

14456,14467,903

14456,14467,903
```

i need to add each line to the xml file sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BusinessConfiguration
        xmlns="http://www.portal.com/schemas/BusinessConfig"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.portal.com/schemas/BusinessConfig BusinessConfiguration.xsd">

        <!-- Sample input file for pin_bill_accts containing parameters for bill run management -->
        <!-- Modify according to guidelines -->
        <BillRunConfiguration>
                <!-- List of DOMs for this bill run -->
                <DOMList>
                        <DOM>---1</DOM>
                </DOMList>
              <BillSegmentList>
                </BillSegmentList>

                <!-- List of billing segments for this bill run -->
                <BillingList>
                </BillingList>
```

i need to add the first 2  record in the csv under the tag   like

```
<BillingList>
                  <Account>12345</Account>
                    <Billinfo>12445</Billinfo>
                </BillingList>
                  <BillingList>
                    <Account>14456</Account>
                   <Billinfo>14467</Billinfo>
                   </BillingList>
```

I have the following code currently:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

NR==FNR{ a[NR]=$0; next; }
/<BillingList>/{
    print;
    gsub("'","",a[++i]);
    n=split(a[i],arr,",");
    if( n!= 3) { next }
    print "\t<Account>",arr[1],"</Account>";
    print "\t<Billinfo>",arr[2],"</Billinfo>";
    next;
}1
```

but it only replaces the first record and then stops.
I am completely new to unix so please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Does the output xml file exist beforehand or are you creating it from scratch? How are you reading the csv file? What does your current code look like?

Comment: i wrote the following code the following code but it only repalces the first  instance                   #!/bin/awk -f
NR==FNR{
          a[NR]=$0;
          next;
}
/<BillingList>/{
          print;
          gsub("'","",a[++i]);
          n=split(a[i],arr,",");
          if( n!= 3) { next }
          print "\t<Account>",arr[1],"</Account>";
          print "\t<Billinfo>",arr[2],"</Billinfo>";
          next;
}1

Comment: You should add that code to the question, rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: it expects the BillingList tag in xml for each line in the csv

Comment: sorry JAL first timer wont happen again

Comment: @Etan Reisner the xml file exits already iam appending to it

Comment: You can't just append to an xml file unless it isn't valid xml in the first place (as it isn't closed).

Comment: How are you using/calling that awk script?

Comment: @etan reisner awk -f file.awk  test.dat text2.xml >final.xml

Comment: the code i wrote did add a single entry to the xml while keeping the xml file syntax intact

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the segment

```
$ awk -F,                                       # use comma as field separator
          'NR>1&&NF{                            # skip first line and blank lines
                print                           # print the following
                   "<BillingList>               
                      <Account>"$1"</Account>    # insert first field
                      <BillInfo>"$2"</BillInfo> # insert second field
                   </BillingList>"
           }' data.txt
```

you can add newlines at the right spots if you want.

Comment: hi thanks can u also please explain the code as well

Comment: hi the code only adds the required segment but i need them appended to the same xml file can u tell me how to do that as well

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <DOMList>
                        <DOM>---1</DOM>
                </DOMList>
              <BillSegmentList>
                </BillSegmentList>

                <!-- List of billing segments for this bill run -->
        <BillingList>
        </BillingList>

     </BillRunConfiguration>

</BusinessConfiguration>
hi i need the segment to be added before  </BillRunConfiguration>  tag in xml can u tell me how to do it

Comment: You can use awk all the way, but perhaps easier with sed in two steps.  `sed -e "/<BillingList>/r awkoutput.txt" template.xml

Comment: Since "<BillingList>" is in the template already you should modify awk to only generate the child nodes.